# Does Georg Heym's poem Louis Capet betray a specific political orientation?

Tags: poetry, german-language, interpretation, georg-heym

The German poet [Georg Heym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georg_Heym) was an important representative of expressionism. Wikipedia tells us that he was a member of the short-lived society or club *Der Neue Club*:

> Other members of this Club included Kurt Hiller, Jakob van Hoddis, and Erwin Loewenson (also known as Golo Gangi); often visiting were Else Lasker-Schüler, Gottfried Benn, and Karl Kraus. Although the Club had no actual stated objective, its members all shared a sense of rebellion against contemporary culture and possessed a desire for political and aesthetic upheaval.

One of his poems is [Louis Capet](https://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Louis_Capet_(Heym)) (available on Wikisource), about the execution of the dethroned French King [Louis XVI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_XVI) in 1793. Like a number of other of Heym's poems (e.g. "Die Irren"), the poem uses the sonnet form, which was a rather traditional genre by 1910. My question is whether the text is representative of the sense of rebellion and the desire for political upheaval that characterise *Der Neue Club*. Or does it point in a different direction?

It is worth mentioning that "Louis Capet" was published in the same volume as another well-known poem, [Robespierre](https://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Robespierre_(Heym)), about the [revolutionary who had argued for executing Louis Capet without trial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximilien_Robespierre#Execution_of_Louis_XVI) and who was guillotined in 1794 after a reign of terror.

---

For those who don't read German, a rough translation of the sonnet is given below.

> The drums sound at the scaffold in a circle,
> which stands like a coffin, covered with black cloth.
> The block stands on it. With it the open salire/sawhorse (?)
> For his body. The guillotine glitters white.
>
> Red standards flutter from full roofs.
> The shouters shriek the price of the window seats.
> In winter it is. But the people grow hot,
> They push forward grumbling. They are made to wait.
>
> Then a noise is heard. It increases. The shouting roars.
> On his cart, Capet comes, bedraggled,
> Covered in excrement, and his hair dishevelled.
>
> He is dragged up quickly. He is stretched.
> His head lies on the block. The guillotine rushes/whizzes.
> Blood spurts from his neck, which is firmly stuck in the hole.